# Can you send cookies with XmlHttpRequest from Safari extension?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

While debugging why my extension doesn't work in Safari (but does for other browsers), noticed that I can send an arbitrary made up HTTP header with XmlHttpRequest in a Safari toolbar extension. But try to do same with header named "Cookie" with same content as before, it doesn't get sent.

So does Safari restrict sending back cookies with requests or you need to follow an alternate process to do so? Seems kind of lame since this blocks functionality of apps that require session state persistence for example. If there's an alternate process, Apple made it harder to maintain session state in extensions (extra work in adapting a web app or other browser extension).

I tested using Safari 5.1.7 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with Charles proxy.

Comment: Think browser sends the associated cookies with request automatically, no need for alternatives, check the situation there, possibility you have forgot set the cookies in client.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the other browsers work fine and automatically pass/persist the session cookie without the developer having to write any cookie handling for the extension. Safari on the other hand won't do that. I tried hacking it by manually parsing cookie and passing it by setting request header with XmlHttpRequest, still Safari won't pass it through, but it does pass through a made up unofficial header that I set like "My-Header: crap data". It just won't pass any header named "Cookie". Makes no sense to me.

Comment: On the other hand, interestingly, Mac OS X desktop widgets/gadgets do allow you to set cookie request header with XmlHttpRequest. It didn't seem to allow reading document.cookie though so I had to do a hack over a web service that relayed the session cookie value for me to then set with an XmlHttpRequest call. Since Safari extensions don't allow setting that request header, I couldn't use the same workaround technique, and thus am stuck.

Comment: For anyone curious what I'm talking about, try getting the Safari extension in the following Google Code project to work. You'll see in the source code that the Mac OS X gadget version makes call to web service to get the session state to then persist with. https://code.google.com/p/autosmsclients/

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? It drives me mad...

Comment: No, I wish I did. No one seems to know of a solution and Apple still hasn't addressed this. I filed a bug with Apple that was marked duplicate of an earlier bug that I have no access to viewing. Here's an OpenRadar clone of bug for reference: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=3168409

Comment: It seems we just have to wait... I found a temporary solution as long as it is not fixed.

Comment: what is your temp solution? would you like to share?

Comment: It is a very specific solution I'm afraid. I avoid the Cross-Domain requests requiring a session by passing a session token through the URL. This works because the targeted websites allow me to do so, it will not work in the majority of the cases.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I would venture to say my solution is more the generic solution that works if the session is cookie based and if one can deploy a custom web service for the Safari extension to use that acts as session bridge between the the actual site/service and the extension.

Comment: Yes your solution is more generic, but the infrastructure is heavier. I think it would be a good idea to answer your question and explain your solution.

Comment: Actually, I forgot that, as mentioned earlier, Safari extension won't allow you to set cookie with XmlHttpRequest though, so my supposed solution doesn't work, it's just for Mac OS X widgets which are a bit less limiting. So yours is the best real solution for now.

Comment: I also failed to set the session cookie. It is ridiculous how complicated it is compared to use Google Chrome or Firefox cross-domain XHR. It doesn't tempt to develop Safari extensions anymore.

Comment: Turns out for Safari extension, what works for me is to set the browser to not block any cookies and website data. So users would have to do that to use the extension. No code changes needed. But that's not cool though.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured I should post the solution that worked for me, that I commented in my own question earlier, for easier viewing by others with similar problem:

Turns out for Safari extension, what works for me is to set the browser to not block any cookies and website data. So users would have to do that to use the extension. No code changes needed. But that's not cool though.

The particular step is `Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Cookies and website data: Always allow` (at least under Safari 10 on Mac OS Yosemite). Although one could try "Allow from websites I visit" to see if that more restrictive option will work or not.

Comment: Did you mean `Safari > Preferences > Privacy` settings (https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2141) or something else?

Comment: Yes, thanks for asking, updated answer. Btw, the Apple support link seems invalid now?